# Cronjob not firing Laravel Function Schedule

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

Based on what I read on the documentation and other SO Questions, I need to add `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` on crontab -e and check with crontab -l just to confirm that the every minute cron was added. The cron item added runs the protected function schedule inside app\Console\Kernel every minute. Everything works on local and development. However on the production, the cron is not running the schedule at all.

What I tried:

Add a dummy cronjob `* * * * * php echo "something" >> /path-to-your-project/storage/logs/test.txt`

- This creates a test.txt file with text `Could not open input file: echo` added every minute. Command is wrong but I know that the cronjob is working. Both working in Development and Production.

Add a `Log::info("TEST");` inside function schedule() both develop and production.

- On Development, I can see the text TEST inside laravel.logs but not in Production.

Note: I tried to manually run `php artisan command:command` and the command does run (with and without sudo).

Note2: I checked /var/logs/cron and I can see both the php artisan and php echo being logged.

Note3: manually running `php artisan schedule:run`, I can see in the terminal the text `No scheduled commands are ready to run.` And the Log inside the schedule was also written.

Is there any part that I missed? Is my setup wrong?

Comment: Which user did you add the cron job for, and do they have appropriate permissions to run `php artisan`, write to logs, etc?  When you manually run `php artisan ...`, are you doing that as the same user?  Anything in your Laravel or PHP logs?

Answer (score 2):

check your php path and set as per your path `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan`

use

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

instead of

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. Unfortunately, `/usr/bin/php /path/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` also does not work. I also run `whereis php` to make sure that I am getting the right path of php.

Comment: at the worst case, I might try to add ***** /usr/bin/php /path/artisan command:command.  (***** will base on what time I will run the command)

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Which part? The worst case or the not working part?

Comment: If not working part, Like the cronjob before, the schedule() function does not run at all.

Comment: this one `php artisan command:command` working directly?

Comment: I meant I will run * 1 * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan command:command >> /dev/null 2>&1 where command:command is the protected $signature of the class command

Comment: okay. its not issuing

Comment: But before I will do so, might try other options. I would like to follow Laravel's standard procedure as much as I can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243648/discussion-between-bhargav-chudasama-and-mr-kenneth).

Comment: The answer might have worked on other cases, but for me it is not working. I am still leaving an upvote here in case someone might stumble on this.

Comment: as per what I said on chat, added the cronjob in sudo crontab -e, the function still does not run.

Comment: While fully specifying paths is always the best option in cronjobs, OP's question clearly shows that is not the problem here. "*Could not open input file: echo*" shows that `php` is found OK.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run my php/artisan script using cron. The command used was:

`* * * * * /bin/php7 /path-to-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Where `/bin/php7` is the command to execute php scripts. Might be because of how the server was setup.